# How do I make my cancel button function

Tags: java

I realized I made an infinite loop and everytime I enter that loop, my cancel button doesn't function and the dialog box continuously pops up.

Here's the code

```
   String buffer = " "; //Input a string into console
   boolean badInput = true;
   boolean badInput2 = true;
   String idNum = ""; //ask for id number 
   String skill = ""; // ask for skill number
   int skillInt = 0; // skill is an int

   //prompt user for file location
   File loc = new File(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please provide the file location: "));
   RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(loc, "rw");

   //prompt user for a command
   String cmd = "start";
   int recLocation = 0;
   while(cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end")!=0){ //stay in program (loop) until end command is given
       cmd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a command (new, old or end): ");

       //creating new entry
       if(cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("new")==0){
           while(badInput){ //keep them in loop until they give the input in the right format
               idNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input an ID number (1 - 20): ");
              // else JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTIONsetDefaultCloseOperation(JOptionPane.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               try{
                   //corresponding int for ID number, which becomes the record location
                   //if number is not 1-20, code below
                   recLocation = Integer.parseInt(idNum);
                   if(recLocation<1 || recLocation>20){
                       System.out.println("Please check that your number is between 1 and 20.");
                   }else{
                       badInput = false;
                       break;  
                   }

               }
               catch(NumberFormatException NF){ // if input isnt a number
                   System.out.println("Please check that your number is in the correct format.");
               }
           }

           //ask for names
           String pName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a player name: ");
           String tName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a team name: ");

           //ask for skill level
           while(badInput2){ //keep them in the loop until they give the input in the right format
               skill = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a skill level (0 - 99): ");
               try{
                   //corresponding int for skill number, to check if in the right format
                   skillInt = Integer.parseInt(skill);
                   if(skillInt<0 || skillInt>99){
                       System.out.println("Please check that your number is between 0 and 99.");
                   }else{
                       badInput2 = false;
                       break;  
                   }

               }
               catch(NumberFormatException NF){ //exception or error thrown if input is not in correct format
                   System.out.println("Please check that your number is in the correct format.");
               }
           }

           String date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input today's date (ex: 25Jun2014): ");

           //formatting id number
           if (idNum.length() < 2){
               idNum = idNum+buffer;
           }
           //formatting player name
           if (pName.length() > 26){
               pName = pName.substring(0, 26);
           } else {
               while(pName.length() < 26){
                   pName = pName+buffer;
               }
           }

           //formatting team name
           if (tName.length() > 26){
               tName = tName.substring(0, 26);
           } else {
               while(tName.length() < 26){
                   tName = tName+buffer;
               }
           }
           //formatting date
           if (date.length() > 9){
               date = date.substring(0, 9);
           } else {
               while(date.length() < 9){
                   date = date+buffer;
               }
           }
           //formatting skill
           if (skill.length() < 2){
               skill = skill+buffer;
           }
           //create full, identifying string
           String fullRecord = idNum + "   " + pName + tName + skill + "   " + date;
           store.seek((RECORD_LENGTH+2) * (recLocation-1));
           store.writeUTF(fullRecord);

           //reset booleans
           badInput = true;
           badInput2 = true;

       }

       //accessing old entry
       if(cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("old")==0){
           idNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input an ID number (1 through 20): ");      
           recLocation = Integer.parseInt(idNum);
           store.seek((RECORD_LENGTH+2)*(recLocation-1));
           String fullRecord = store.readUTF();

           //interpret information from full string
           try
           {idNum = fullRecord.substring(0, 5);
           String pName = fullRecord.substring(5, 31);
           String tName = fullRecord.substring(31, 57);
           skill = fullRecord.substring(57, 62);
           String date = fullRecord.substring(62, 71);
           System.out.println("ID: "+idNum+" NAME: "+pName+" TEAM: "+tName+" SKILL: "+skill+" DATE: "+date);
           }
           catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException S){
               System.out.println("No record found at that location.");
           }
       }

      // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "good bye");
   }
```

Sorry if I didn't format this right. It's my first time. I was wondering how I could get the cancel button to exit the loop. I tried using `if (cmd == null) System.exit(0);` but that doesn't seem to function. I'm really novice at java and I have little experience so bear with me please.

Comment: See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The key here is MINIMAL. In other words, produce the least amount of code that allows us to reproduce the problem. All the stuff in the middle of your loop is irrelevant and just makes the question hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest using equalsIgnoreCase as your String comparison instead of compareIgnoreCase: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

```
while(!cmd.equalsToIgnoreCase("end")) {
```

Then if one of the JOptionPane.showInputDialog()'s returns null which would mean they'd cancelled, you could have an if statement that sets the cmd string to "end". I think though you should probably try to simplify the loop because it's got a lot in it all in the one block. That makes it hard to debug.